# Variable is not declared in the scope error in c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, scope, declaration

I'm new bee in c++! I'm to iterate over integers using the for loop, but getting the error

```
               error: ‘frame’ was not declared in this scope
               auto position_array = (*frame)[i][j];
```

But as you can see in the code below it is declared

```cpp
    auto ds = data_file.open_dataset(argv[1]);
    // auto frame = data_file.read_frame(ds, 0); // inside the loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        auto frame  = data_file.read_frame(ds, i);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nsamples; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j <= 2; ++j) { // j<=2 assign all columns 
            auto position_array = (*frame)[i][j];
        }
        corr.sample(frame);
    }
    corr.finalise();
```

It works fine if I use the commented second line. But now I want to iterate over the second variable of **data_file.read_frame(ds, i)** and the error comes up! What am I doing wrong? Do I need to declare **int frame = 0;** before the for loop? For the brevity I just post the code with the error, incase some one need to see the whole code you're welcome!!

Comment: Your compiler is absolutely correct. The `frame` variable only exists on this line: `auto frame  = data_file.read_frame(ds, i);` it no longer exists after that because the body of the for loop is just the single line.

Comment: You’re declaring the variable inside the loop so it’s not usable outside. It’s unclear what the types are and what exactly should happen. Probably you need to declare an array of something and then read the data into that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a nested for loop.  Using

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    auto frame  = data_file.read_frame(ds, i);

    for (size_t j = 0; j < nsamples; ++j) {
        for (size_t k = 0; k <= 2; ++k) { // j<=2 assign all columns 
            auto position_array = (*frame)[i][j];
        }
        corr.sample(frame);
    }
}
```

Lets you get each `frame`, and then process each element of each frame.

Answer (score 2):

This for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    auto frame  = data_file.read_frame(ds, i);
```

is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    auto frame  = data_file.read_frame(ds, i);
}
```

That is the sub-statement of the for loop forms its one scope. And outside the scope the variable frame is not visible.

Moreover the variable `frame` is created anew in each iteration of the loop.

From the C++ 17 Standard (9.4 Selection statements)

> 1. ...The substatement in a selection-statement (each substatement, in the else form of the if statement) implicitly defines a block scope
>    (6.3). If the substatement in a selection-statement is a single
>    statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten
>    to be a compound-statement containing the original substatement.